# What is considered to be unknowable?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge

Has anyone tried to classify what is considered to be unknowable in the physical world to define it more precisely? I can think of some basic classes of ideas and some, perhaps disputable, examples for each class.

- **Lack of information transfer**: What happened before the big bang? What happened on a specific day 100,000 years ago if no historical data/information exists about that day?
- **Paradoxical/Self-referential**: One cannot experience their own death; one cannot see one's own eyes without a reflective surface etc.
- **Senses**: Experiencing a spatial dimension beyond 3. Anything beyond the five senses.
- **Mathematical**: Godel's Incompleteness Theorem and other properties of arithmetic formal systems.

The question linked below mentions [Fitch's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fitch-paradox/). I'm afraid I don't have the background or understand of notation to comprehend the article at SEP. If someone could briefly summarize and explain its relevance to my question I would appreciate it.

**Related:**

[Is there a philosophy of things that could not be discovered?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15302/is-there-a-philosophy-of-things-that-could-not-be-discovered/15316#15316)

Comment: What happened before the Big Bang is not necessarily unknowable, unexperiencable can be knowable too, most of modern physics is beyond the 5 senses, and undecidable sentences become decidable in stronger theories (e.g. Godel sentence of arithmetic is provable in set theory). Isn't it a paradox to know of something unknowable? As Wittgenstein wrote, "*a nothing will serve just as well as something about which nothing can be said*".

Comment: Something may be beyond the 5 senses but in the case of science, it is because it there is some kind of information available for us to infer. Generally, when I hear about interpretations of before the Big Bang I seem to see a lot of "we can't know because there is no way to test it". I don't see it as a paradox to know of something unknowable... there is a difference to me between asking/having knowledge of an unknowable question and getting the answer to that question. Even if my categories are wrong, what then is unknowable?

Comment: "We can't know" because we can't test it *today*. We can not know today what we can or can not know tomorrow, there is no known "unknowable". On realist philosophies there can in principle be unknowable things (like Kant's thing in itself), but by their very definition there is nothing we can know of them. On other views (e.g. Peirce's pragmatism or phenomenology), "unknowable" is an unintelligible term. I think what you have in mind are horizonal things, we get hints that they are there but do not have means of grasping them yet. This is a relative and time specific notion, "known unknowns".

Comment: See [Traub's interview](https://www.edge.org/3rd_culture/traub/traub_p3.html):"*What are some of the reasons why a scientific question might be unanswerable? I'll limit myself to just three here. The first is that insufficient data has survived. That can be a problem in ur-linguistics, archaeology, and history. The second is that contingent events, sometimes called frozen accidents, may limit our ability to explain certain phenomena... Finally, resources, such as energy, may simply not be available in our part of the universe to discriminate among contesting theories about the universe*".

Comment: Regarding "unknowable" being an unintelligible term. I think I understand: We can't call something unknowable because the only way to know if it was unknowable or not is to know about it. But if it can be known then it is was never "unknowable" to begin with. Traub's position seems to bear some similarity to my original list (insufficient data/information) but I guess he isn't saying its unknowable, just not answerable, which I guess I considered to be the same thing in my list.

Comment: What about paradoxical statements or self-referential? Do these ideas not matter because these statement have no application to the real world and are nonsensical linguistically?

Comment: There is *relatively* unknowable, something that will remain unknown even if we generously project our current abilities. Say what Aristotle was doing on his 8th birthday is unknown and will likely be unknowable for the foreseeable future (but there might be a temposcope one day). I think you mean not so much self-referential paradoxes as Godel type sentences, which can be proved undecidable by using self-reference. To realists this again is relative, to a formalism, and can be decided by enriching it. Intuitionists say that truth is provability, so there is nothing there to know.

Comment: Well now, soon we may  be rehearsing the discussion in Buddhism about the nature of the Buddha's omniciscience.

Comment: You might try:  "What We Cannot Know" by :Marcus Du Sautoy              Also a You Tube Presentation...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reeU09R4TIA

Comment: To @Conifold. About your remark, "most of modern physics is beyond the 5 senses". I disagree since the only part of physics that matters are it's measurable predictions and in that perspective there can be nothing in it that is beyond sensory experience.

Comment: @VectorShift "Beyond sensory experience" does not mean beyond measurements and experimental testing. Electrons, quarks, and processes inside neutron stars, or even the Sun, are certainly beyond sensory experience. But we can posit them and infer observable predictions from our positing, *those* are accessible to the senses. Of course, we can posit many different things giving the same predictions. This leads to the problem of [underdeterminantion of scientific theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination) due to sensory inaccessibility of theoretical entities.

Comment: @Conifold If there are different formulations that are predicatively equivalent but correspond to different intermediate mathematical structures then both are equally complete, not underdetermined. There is no "reality" beyond the predictions. It is the strength of mathematics that there are many systems that are conceptually very different in details but are actually functionally identical (isomorphic) to each other.

Comment: I feel the question is interesting but spoilt by restricting it to the physical world. It becomes philosophically unimportant. Also, it is not clear to me that a knowledge of what is prior to the Big Bang qualifies as knowledge 'in' the physical world.

Answer (score 1):

Kant arguably classified things in this manner, although not with the same categories as you suggest.  He has two categories: Things as they appear to us through the mediation of our sense, or in other words, empirical reality, and [noumena](https://www.britannica.com/topic/noumenon), things as they actually are in an unknowable objective reality.  The idea is that all we can know is what our senses tell us, but that we can only assume that what our senses have told us is accurate.

Fitch's paradox is an attempt at a logical proof of the following statement:

> If there is at least one unknown truth, then there is at least one unknowable truth

The main idea is that we can't know "*X* is an unknown truth" because that requires us to know "*X* is a truth", which equates to knowing *X*, which means *X* cannot be unknown.  Therefore "*X* is an unknown truth" is unknowable, yet true (in the case that any such *X* exists).  This is yet another category, things that are logically unknowable.

Answer (score -2):

Kant used the word "noumenon", which has not been accepted by all dictionaries. The word can refer to that, which was previously "unknowable", being "thing-in-itself", thus, that, which is underneath phenomenal shapes (forms), which are known. As science progresses, phenomena are becoming more, and noumena are becoming less, because newly discovered phenomena replace parts of previously unknown noumena.

Comment: I voted this down for being a misunderstanding of Kant.

Comment: Would you support your opinion with an excerpt from Kant self about noumenon. Preferably not a paraphrase. I support my opinion with Kant's own description "thing-in-itself". Modern science delves deeper into insides, therefore logically, new phenomena replaces noumena. You probably have the more metaphysical cosmological view of noumena, which in my view is not in the spirit of Kant's philosophy. He demarcated metaphysical views away from science and regarded philosophy as a scientific ontological process. Added to that, I am not a specialist on Kant. Read only two books of himself. @PeterJ

Comment: I recommend this essay. It is not quite fair to Kant imho, but it is an excellent overview.and much easier to understand than anything Kant wrote. https://philosophynow.org/issues/118/An_Overdue_Appearance_of_Immanuel_Kant

Comment: @PeterJ. Thank you, but I am interested at this time of my learning to read only what Kant wrote himself.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd say it's the hard way to get to know him, but also the most scholarly and respectful way so good on you. The idea that 'newly discovered phenomena replace previously unknown noumena' is, however, utterly wrong.

Comment: @PeterJ why is the idea wrong, iyo? Maybe we should discuss it. Last week i received a message to rather discuss something at a chat platform, than here. Do not know however how to do that.

Comment: you have misunderstood Kant

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda you are a cosmological thinker and i am an ontological thinker. In my opinion your cosmological view is faulty, not only with regard to Kant, but most other things as well, because cosmological people claim to see things, which are not humanly possible to see. Bottom line is, most opinions of me will seem like misunderstandings to you, because we base our opinions on different presuppositions.

Comment: Marquard - It would be inappropriate to argue here but I feel you need to study Kant more closely. Cosmology and ontology are not separate studies. How could they be? You are dismissing the Swami's expert view on the basis of some muddled ideas that bowdlerise both his view and Kant's. Most certainly he is not claiming to see things that are impossible to see.  For his view speculation is not confused with knowledge. I strongly suggest you read the article I mentioned.

Comment: @PeterJ cosmological thinkers and ontological thinkers are miles apart in their presuppositions therefore they usually do not agree. A good example, which demonstrates the point is Anselm's ontological explanation of God, which is criticized by Aquinas in his Summa Theologica. Aquinas had a cosmological argument for God.

Comment: An argument for the existence of God is an ontological argument, as is an argument for the existence of anything. It would be impossible to have a cosmology and not an ontology and vice versa.